# Handlebars load template from sibling folder

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

I have the following folder setup

- templates

  - partials
  - portfolio

I would now like to include a handlebars template from portfolio into a template from partials, however it does not work.

I tried many variations of:

```
{{>"../portfolio/item"}}
```

Is there a way to do this and if so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I figured out this is not possible.
However I settled for using a base layout with inlines.

This article helped me for my new approach: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/the-hidden-power-of-handlebars-partials/

I created "layouts/base.hbs" and inside used includes:

```
{{> portfolio/item
  hero-src="http://fpoimg.com/500x200"
  hero-alt="Hero 1 alt title"
}}
```

Comment: what was the solution that you used? Could you add that for posterity?

Comment: Hey @theprogrammer I am sorry, but this page does not exist anymore. I think I just created a layout file "layouts/base.hbs" and used inlines inside this file like so:

{{> includes/hero
  hero-src="http://fpoimg.com/500x200"
  hero-alt="Hero 1 alt title"
}}